# Create User with MySQLi Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a script using PHP and MySQLi with prepared statements. The purpose is to create a new user on a MySQL server, however preparing the statement fails with no further information as to why.

```
$query = 'CREATE USER ?@`10.1.1.%` IDENTIFIED BY ?;';

if ($stmt = $newdb->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $db_username, $db_password);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
    // Database user created successfully
    } else {
    die(errorJSON('db', 'create', 22));
}

$stmt->close();
} else {
    die(errorJSON('db', 'create', 3));
}
```

Any ideas why perparing this statement would fail?

Thank You.

Comment: please include error from mysql -- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hi ! Can you give us a little more information : where is this script failing ? What is the error type (php or mysql) ? What do you get when you echo $stmt->error after a failure ?

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem, preparing that statement fails, i don't know, why:

mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? IDENTIFIED BY ?' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print `$stmt->error` (and optionally `$stmt->errno`) when testing the success/failure of your queries.  For instance:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // Database user created successfully
    } else {
        errorJSON('db', 'create', 22)
        die($stmt->error);
    }
```

The above is quite a bad example - likely I've messed up the logic of your error reporting itself - but that is how you would retrieve the error and print/log it.

Comment: This is not the answer on question