# How to write "create user ?" with MySQL prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, prepare

I tried:

```
SET @user = 'foo@localhost';
SET @pass = 'bar';
SET @sql = 'CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
PREPARE stmt FROM $sql;
```

and I get error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? IDENTIFIED BY ?'
```

I also tried multiple variants how to define variables, but still without any luck.

```
SET @user = "'foo'@'localhost'";
SET @sql = 'CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
```

and even

```
SET @user = 'foo';
SET @host = 'localhost';
SET @sql = 'CREATE USER ?@? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
```

Quite similar question was already asked more than 2 years ago, but there still is no useful answer :(
[Create User with MySQLi Prepared Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258035/create-user-with-mysqli-prepared-statement)

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Just MySQL from console in this case, but I can use PHP too if needed.

Answer (score 5):

This is the only way how I managed to create a user, unfortunately it doesn't use placeholders for the user variables:

```
SET @user := 'foo';
SET @host := 'localhost';
SET @pass := 'bar';
SET @sql := CONCAT("CREATE USER ", QUOTE(@user), "@", QUOTE(@host), " IDENTIFIED BY ", QUOTE(@pass));
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

P.S. `{CREATE | RENAME | DROP} USER` statements should be supported starting from MySQL 5.1.12

Comment: +1 for a legitmiate use of [`QUOTE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) which is really the sanest thing that can be done here, since `CREATE USER` doesn't support `?` placeholders.  As long as there's no injection opportunity when initially setting the variables (which, if there is, can be fixed by first preparing and executing `SET @user = ?` ... etc.), or passing args into a stored procedure where this code (possibly, I'm guessing) lives, this should be a winner.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot,  another thing, there will be no performance benefits of prepared statements, since placeholders are not used...

Comment: True, it has to be re-prepared for each run, but if someone is creating new MySQL server users at a rate that a they're concerned about how fast it can be done, then they have a whole new problem.  I assume OP's motivation for using a prepared statement was safety rather than performance in this case.

Comment: Yeah this way it works, but then it's not big deal to use prepared statements. What I wanted to accomplish is to create pure MySQL script to generate 10-100 new users by changing just variables and use Execute and not rewrite "CREATE USER ..." every time.

Comment: you don't need to rewrite the `sql`, just assign new values to the variables

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd But I'll need to rewrite all these 4 SET rows (new values), then prepare again and then execute, right? So basically I'll need to rewrite all 6 rows for every user :) It's not big deal in fact, but ... I'm just trying to understand this.

Comment: the following solution differs from placeholders, only in speed and security (theoretically). The usage is exactly the same... Assign new values to the `@user`, `@hos`t, `@pass`... I would suggest you to create stored procedure based on this solution

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd yeah stored procedure will be the best solution I guess. I'll accept your answer in a few days if nothing better will come up here and I guess it will not.