# CREATE USER fails with Mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a simple PHP script to create and assign attributes to an SQL user. The query works fine if no parameters are used, but fails otherwise.

Works fine

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass');
$sql = "CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Both username and password are `?`

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass');
$sql = "CREATE USER '?'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '?'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$uname = "carn";
$pass = "pass";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

Both username and password are `?`

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass');
$sql = 'CREATE USER "?"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "?"';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$uname = "carn";
$pass = "pass";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

Error in syntax, check documentation

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass');
$sql = "CREATE USER ?@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$uname = "carn";
$pass = "pass";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

Error in syntax, check documentation

```
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'pass');
$sql = "CREATE USER `?`@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY `?`";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$uname = "carn";
$pass = "pass";
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $uname, $pass);
$stmt->execute();
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. This might be an issue with the way I'm using quotes I saw two related questions here on SO but none of them answered properly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I said it might be an issue, not that I'm sure of it. I tried all combinations I could think of, for all other queries I never wrap `?` with anything and it works fine, here however `bind_param()` fails.

Comment: *"Might"* ? - More like "is". Placeholders cannot have quotes and/or ticks, far as I remember.

Comment: DDL statements like `CREATE TABLE` do not work with parameters. `CREATE USER` is likely the same.

Comment: @Fred-ii- 4th example is the correct usage though

Comment: @aron9forever ok. I removed my possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With prepared statement you can use only limited subset of queries. Create user not included.

You can try INSERT into `mysql.user` table, something like

```
INSERT INTO `mysql`.`user` (Host,User,Password)VALUES(?,?,password(?));
```

Besides, with users created dynamically you are doing something wrong

Comment: So it's impossible to do it like this? If all names and passwords are generated by me and not user input, should I just go for no params?

Comment: Decided to go with no parameterization since there is no user input, username is generated by appending numeric id to a word, and password just random alpha characters.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put single quotes around the `?`, bind_param() will take care of it.

However, there is another issue that you can't use placeholders for `CREATE USER` statements in MySQL.

See [How to write "create user ?" with MySQL prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647115/how-to-write-create-user-with-mysql-prepared-statement) for a way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks, see the 4th example, that's how I usually write them, I just tried all combinations of quotation I could think of before posting the question.